# How to add woocommerce add to cart button with out adding its regular and sale price.

Tags: woocommerce, product

I have ha custom product and i want to show a add to cart button with out adding its regular price and sale price . How i can accomplish this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand - what price do you want to turn up in the shopping cart then?

Comment: i want to use pricing table prices instead of sale price and regular